# 'Unable to parse the format string "claimID != '' & userID = %@"'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to write a `NSPredicate` to fetch userID and claimID and I am getting the below error.

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "claimID != '' & userID = %@"'`

My Code is-

```
+(NSArray*)fetchNotificationsWithPredicate {
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"claimID != '' & userID = %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"usernmae"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self fetchNotifications]);
    NSArray *loginUsers = [DBUtils createAndExecuteFetchRequestWithPredicate:@"Notification" predicate:predicate];
    return loginUsers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [predicate string format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB), it looks like `&` isn't a valid operator. You either want `AND` or `&&`. So:

```
@"claimID != '' && userID = %@"
```

or

```
@"claimID != '' AND userID = %@"
```

(This may well not be the *only* issue. I've never used this API, and I'm not an iOS developer. This is just from inspection of the documentation...)

Comment: Inspection of the documentation... What a revolutionary new concept! That will never catch on.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"claimID != '' AND userID MATCHES %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"usernmae"]];
```

**Note:** for number matching use '=' and for string matching use  '*MATCHES*'

Comment: Hi Jamil thanks for your answer but now I am getting a new error that is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid predicate: nil RHS'

Comment: check its value is either nil

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"usernmae"]

Comment: it is working now it was my fault I was putting @"usernmae" instead of @"username".